# sharing internet through wired or wifi lan devices on router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, home-networking

```
                              device_A
wall --> modem --> router ---<
                              device_B
```

A is a streaming device and I cannot specify static IP, it just connects to whatever it is plugged into and obtains IP from DHCP. B is a windows 10 pc but has no wifi

A & B are connected by cable to the router. I want A to access internet though B so A can use the VPN on device B. Is this possible with this wiring configuration?

Is this possible with wifi devices connected to same router? device B has no wifi connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

This will only work if you can do three things that you may not be able to do:

1. Configure the router not to respond to device A's DHCP request.
2. Configure device B to respond to device A's DHCP request.
3. Configure device B to act as a "router on a stick" and support two networks, one for it to get Internet access and one for it to provide access through its VPN to other machines.

If you can do these three things, it will work. Device B will need to respond to device A's DHCP request and assign it an IP address inside the network that it provides Internet access to using the VPN. Device B's address on the network it provide VPN access through needs to be device A's default gateway. Device B will likely need to do NAT to impersonate device A unless the VPN supports a mapped subnet.

Comment: thank's for the answer. looking into my options